# Load HTML in place with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to load a piece of HTML from a list of HTML inserts

```
$('#placeholder1').html($('.html3').html());

<td id="placeholder1">
 // place html here
</td>

<div style="display:hidden">
   <div class="html1">
        // some HTML 1 here
    </div>
    <div class="html2">
        // some HTML 2 here
    </div>
    <div class="html3">
        // some HTML 3 here
    </div>
</div>
```

Does not seem to work. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: works ok for me: http://jsfiddle.net/yqXRp/

Comment: Is your JS code wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function () { ...code here... });`? If not, your elements do not exist yet.

Comment: Well, it should work : http://jsfiddle.net/YeyBj/

Comment: @soju & @Jamiec: It works because JSFiddle automatically adds your JS code into a `ready` block.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped my IDs and it did not work... Dah! Works now. For a moment I thought I needed more coffee. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your jQuery code in a `ready` block.

```
$(function(){
  $('#placeholder1').html($('.html3').html());
});
```

**Note:** `$(function(){});` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Answer (score 4):

Place the jquery code after the html is rendered.

or use this like

```
// Doing this wait for js to run until the DOM is loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#placeholder1').html($('.html3').html());
});
```